# How to update 'myself' variables from within a block

Tags: netlogo

In netlogo 5.3.1, assume:

```
marketmakers-tier1-own [ trading-capital ]
```

I want to do this:

```
ask other marketmakers-tier1 [
  let T-capital [ trading-capital ] of myself
  let T-cost some-amount

  ;; do some stuff

  ; now update myself's trading-capital
  set [ trading-capital ] of myself ( T-capital - T-cost )
]
```

Produces this error on the **set** command:

> This isn't something you can use "set" on.

Any suggestions I will appreciate.

Comment: Just `ask myself [set trading-capital ...]`
But I doubt you really want this particular program logic.

Comment: Ah!!  Simple. Thank you.  Indeed, the construct might not be optimal, but it is a first attempt. Appreciate it @Alan !!